# JQuery causing fadeIn twice?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve the effect where when you click a new item the previously clicked item is fadeOut. But when you click the same item twice it fades in Again, and i would like it NOT to fade in twice.

Since i am still learning JS could you please also add reasoning to why mine isnt working and what needs to be done to achieve it, so then i will be able to self learn better :)

I wast able to load the code input module so here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".qs").click(function() {
jQuery(".qs").siblings(".ans").fadeOut(600).not(jQuery(this));
  jQuery(this).siblings(".ans").fadeIn(600);
});
});

<table class="faqs" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="qs"><span>1. How does LenDen Work?</span></td>
    <td class="ans">This is an example Answer with more Length testing.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="qs"><span>2. Different modes of transaction?</span></td>
    <td class="ans">Answer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Alex

Comment: not very understand your question, always show only one answer, click 2 hide answer 1 and show answer 2, click 1 hide answer 2 and show answer 1?

Comment: @ Savenz Savisaar Kulbach : I hope this is what you are looking for [Prevent FadeIn Twice](http://jsfiddle.net/349Laj29/4/) . Do notify If this meets your need then i will post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this might just solve your problem:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".qs").click(function() {

    if(jQuery(this).hasClass("selected")){
        return;
    }
    jQuery(".qs").siblings(".ans").fadeOut();
    jQuery(this).siblings(".ans").fadeIn();
    jQuery(".qs").removeClass("selected");
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");


    });
    });
```

You will also need the css:

```
<style>
.active .units { display:block }
.ans {display: none}
.selected{}
</style>
```

Ofcourse there couls be better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very understand your question, will it always show only one answer?

click 2 hide answer 1 and show answer 2,

click 1 hide answer 2 and show answer 1?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#location').on('change', function(){
        reset();
    });
    function reset(){
     $("#wing").val("");
     $("#post").val("");
    }

    $(".qs").click(function() {
        var others = $(".qs").not($(this)).siblings(".ans");
        others.fadeOut(600);
        $(this).siblings(".ans").fadeIn(600);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well, you are expecting the behaviour of the sort provided below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".qs").click(function() {
        jQuery(".qs").not(jQuery(this )).siblings(".ans").fadeOut(600);
        jQuery(this).siblings(".ans").fadeIn(600);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st20h3w0/)